# putty command line to paste large amounts of commands

Tags: command-line, putty, copy-paste

I´d like to know which command line parameters I have to set when I use the putty.exe from the command line so as to achieve to paste several commands in putty command line without breaking my pasting my copied text. I-ve read that it can be achieved in the putty UI if whe change the default Window->Selection->"Action on mouse buttons" to "Windows".

Thanks,
Luis

Answer (score 1):

Rutty can be used:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/rutty/?source=typ_redirect

In Cisco console, you can also configure:

https://networkthings.wordpress.com/2015/09/13/copypaste-en-la-consola-cisco/

If you have to use hyperterminal, try changing ASCII set up(increasing line delay). You can do this under File > properties > settings > ASCII setup.